# Git - bad config on line 69 in .gitconfig

Tags: git, macos

I started to learn git a I'm making folder to repository.

In folder which I need init is only one index.html and app.js nothing else.

I entered:

```
$ git init
```

and error was following

> fatal: bad config line 69 in file /Users/matusrebros/.gitconfig

Here is lines from `.gitconfig`

```
    66 # Merge GitHub pull request on top of the current branch or,
    67 # if a branch name is specified, on top of the specified branch
    68 mpr = "!f() { \
    69
    70 # Detect whitespace errors when applying a patch
    71 whitespace = fix
```

On line 69 I have nothing.

So I need make folder as repository with command `$ git init`.

Comment: Line 68 seems to end abruptly, most likely it is that line.

Comment: but error saying its in 69

Comment: I understand that, but could you try removing or editing line 68, just to humor me?

Comment: How can i edit it to be good?

Comment: Try removing it for now, initial step would be to identify the location of the problem, then afterwards you can attempt to fix it. So copy the file to a backup, remove that line, then see if git is happy. If it is, you know it has something to do with that line. Then restore from backup and keep troubleshooting.

Comment: But that line seems to define an alias that is incomplete, my guess would be that it is missing the rest of the command after that backslash, including an ending double quote.

Comment: And combine that with the `whitespace = fix` line, which is probably `apply.whitespace`, it seems your gitconfig file is missing a chunk in the middle there, basically, it looks to me like your gitconfig file got corrupted.

Comment: I removed 68 and 69 line and in terminal git wrote "Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/matusrebros/www/git/.git/" is it good?

Comment: It means git was now able to create the repository. However, that git config looks weird, I would definitely look at the settings inside to see if they still make sense to you.

Comment: So what I should to do?

Comment: Well, presumably you *created* that gitconfig file? So verify that it still looks correct. If you didn't create it, from where did you get it?

Comment: I instal GIT with .pcg file on MAC and it was created automatically, right?

Comment: @MatúšRebroš, yes the error says line 69, but most often than not in most programming languages, I've used errors often blame the line below for an error the line above.  For example, if you forget a semicolon at the end of a statement in php it will always blame the line below where the error actually is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the snippet you posted, it looks like the `.gitconfig` file is from here:

https://github.com/mathiasbynens/dotfiles/blob/master/.gitconfig

That part of the file where you had the error was missing a chunk of text. It was supposed to look like this:

```
    # Merge GitHub pull request on top of the current branch or,
    # if a branch name is specified, on top of the specified branch
    mpr = "!f() { \
        declare currentBranch=\"$(git symbolic-ref --short HEAD)\"; \
        declare branch=\"${2:-$currentBranch}\"; \
        if [ $(printf \"%s\" \"$1\" | grep '^[0-9]\\+$' > /dev/null; printf $?) -eq 0 ]; then \
            git fetch origin refs/pull/$1/head:pr/$1 && \
            git checkout -B $branch && \
            git rebase $branch pr/$1 && \
            git checkout -B $branch && \
            git merge pr/$1 && \
            git branch -D pr/$1 && \
            git commit --amend -m \"$(git log -1 --pretty=%B)\n\nCloses #$1.\"; \
        fi \
    }; f"


[apply]

    # Detect whitespace errors when applying a patch
    whitespace = fix
```

If you like, you could replace your `.gitconfig` with the original at the link I posted above. Or since it looks like **Lasse Vågsæther Karlsen** helped you get it working, you can leave it alone.